# Line wrapping mathmode in ACM article-proc style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, wrap, acm

I am using the ACM document class acm_proc_article-sp.  It is a two column page style.  I keep running into a badbox where I have some line of text, and then a short equation in mathmode.
For example,

```
... such that $\exists x.p(x)$.
```

Leads to $\exists x.p(x)$ being outside of the margin (leaking into the middle of the page).  One solution, is to rewrite the sentence using either fewer or more words to force it to fit, or to force a wrap.  However this is not ideal because if you decide to change something earlier in the document, you can end up back in the situation, again having to mangle the sentence length.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that any TeX typesetting engine refrains from breaking lines while in math mode; when it does this takes place before a \relation operator. In your simple exression $\exists x.p(x)$ there are no breakpoints suitable for any typesetting engine; manually dividing after \exists would not be typegraphically and mathematically correct.

What you can do is to typeset the paragraph within a sloppypar environmet.

Alternatively you might enclose the paragraph (with an explicit \par command at the end) whithin a group where you set \tolerance = 3000, for example, so as to loosen a little bit the paragraph lines, whithout letting them become too uggly; chose the lowest value of the tolerance that allows a nice paragraph; the default value, if you do not spacify anything, is something around 150; notice that 9999 is the maximum finite tolerance value; 10000 for TeX is equivalent to "infinity", therfore with this value the paragraph is allowed to be typeset in the uggliest way.